# Wordpress upload images path not showing in textfield

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a plugin and in plugin i want to use wordpress media upload, it upload images successfully.

I already enqeue the "media-upload" and "thick box" Files

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_lsp_scripts');
function wp_lsp_scripts(){
    wp_register_style('lsp_admin_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'includes/css/lsp_style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('lsp_admin_css');

    wp_enqueue_style('wp-color-picker');
    wp_enqueue_script('cp-script-handle', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'includes/js/lsp_custom.js', array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true);

    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');

    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}
```

But the issue is that the path of the image not showing in text field

Here is my code

upload_image.php:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
           <td width="22%">
               <label>
                    Upload New Image
               </label>
           </td>
           <td width="56%">
               <input type="text" size="50" name="lsp_slide_image" id="lsp_slide_image" class="lsp_upload_url" />
           </td>
           <td width="22%">
               <input id="lsp_upload_button" class="lsp_upload_button" type="button" name="upload_button" value="<?php _e('Upload Images','lsp'); ?>">
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td>
               <input type="submit" name="lsp_save_images" value="Save Image">
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

custome.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.lsp_upload_button').click(function() {
        targetfield = jQuery(this).prev('.lsp_upload_url');
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
        return false;
    });

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
        jQuery(targetfield).val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
    }

});
```

Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got my mistake

Here is the solution:

Firstly i separate the colorpicker and media upload file

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_lsp_scripts');
function wp_lsp_scripts(){
    wp_register_style('lsp_admin_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'includes/css/lsp_style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('lsp_admin_css');

    wp_enqueue_style('wp-color-picker');
    wp_enqueue_script('cp-script-handle', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'includes/js/lsp_colorpicker.js', array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true);

    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');

    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');

    wp_register_script('lsp_media_box', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'includes/js/lsp_media_box.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('lsp_media_box');
}
```

Without changing in "upload_image.php" file, i make and edit the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.lsp_upload_button').click(function() {
        targetfield = jQuery(this).parents().find('.lsp_upload_url');
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
        return false;
    });

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
        jQuery(targetfield).val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
    }

});
```

First i use this code

```
targetfield = jQuery(this).prev('.lsp_upload_url');
```

and in html i put input field in one `<td>` and upload button put in another `<td>`
so the `.prev` not working.

If i put input field and upload button in same `<td>` my previous code work perfectly